# Add automatic refresh to a div with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, var

The div works perfectly, but adding a new value to it results in **NaN**. But when updating the page, the div shows the updated value.

Would there be any way to add an automatic **refresh** to this div?

```js
$(function () {

         $(".but").on("click",function(e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          $(".content").hide();
          $("#"+this.id+"div").show();

        });

    });
```

```css
.content { display:none };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="but" type="button" id="Id">Load</button>


<div id="Iddiv" class="content">

  <h2>content div</h2>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code you used to "add a new value?"

Comment: I feel i'm not understanding the question. What's this "value" you are talking about? and how it interacts wit the div?

Comment: I'm trying to add a refresh button inside the 'Iddiv' div. When I click the 'Load' button a div is displayed below, and I'm trying to add a refresh button inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {

         $(".but").on("click",function(e) {
         
        
         
         if ($("h2")[0].innerHTML=='content div'){
            $("h2")[0].innerHTML="";
         }else {
         
            $("h2")[0].innerHTML='content div';
         }
          
          
          
          
        });

    });
```

```css
.content { display:block };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="but" type="button" id="Id">Load</button>


<div id="Iddiv" class="content">

  <h2></h2>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a refresh button inside the 'Iddiv' div :/.

Answer (score 1):

Given that hadent supplied where the new data comes from. Here are 2 examples.

**Example one:**

```
<button class="btn1" type="button" id="Id" data-newtxt="Example Text">Load</button>

<div id="section1">
    <h2>content div</h2>
    <span class="new-data"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.btn1').click(function() {
        $('.section1 .new-data').text( $(this).data('newtxt') );
    })
});
</script>
```

**Example two:**

```
<button class="btn2" type="button" id="Id" data-newtxt="Example Text">Load</button>
<div class="hidden-div">Some example content</div>

<div id="section2">
    <h2>content div</h2>
    <span class="new-data"></span>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.btn2').click(function() {
        $('.section2 .new-data').text( $('.hidden-div').text() );
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a refresh button inside the 'Iddiv' div. When I click the 'Load' button a div is displayed below, and I'm trying to add a refresh button inside it.